# Ionic slow before transition starts

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk

As many other Ionic developers I'm experiencing slow state changes on Android. My problem; it takes a few hundred milliseconds before the app starts to make the transition. I'm using native transitions and crosswalk, so the when the transition is being performed it's smooth.

My best guess is that the timeline looks like this:

```
1) Button is pressed, activating the state change.
2) App loads the new state
3) Transition being performed to the new state
```

Step number 2 is what seems to take a few hundred milliseconds, and I really thought this would be solved by Ionics view caching, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

My views are mostly static, so my idea is to find a way to cache the views properly, and manually trigger when the cache should be cleared.

Do you know how this can be done? Or if you have a better idea of how this can be solved, I'd really appreciate it if you could share your advice.